# How to use the the words "rollover hours" correctly in this sentence and context

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, sentence

I am writing bullet points of what is included in a website maintenance service. The way I have phrased the sentence is "**Rollover up to 12 Unused Hours**". I am not sure if that is correct. How may I use the words "**rollover hours**" correctly in order to express that if you don't use the maintenance hours we can rollover your hours for next month? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "Rollover hours" is not a thing.  Try "unused hours".

Comment: If you want the verb, it's roll over:  you may roll over up to 12 unused hours.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you for your comment and Xanne thank you for complementing his comment. Now I understand how to use it correctly.

Comment: I agree with Xanne: Roll over up to 12 unused hours. As a bullet point.

Answer (score 1):

I think your original example is pretty clear, but here are some alternatives:

- "Up to 12 unused maintenance hours may be rolled over each month"
- "Up to 12 unused maintenance hours may be carried over into the next month"
- "Unused hours may be rolled over, to a limit of 12"